# Sublime Text 3 smlnj REPL not printing exceptions

Tags: exception, sublimetext3, sml, read-eval-print-loop, smlnj

When an exception is raised in the code I don't get any message or anything at all printed. For example the following code:

```
fun test n = 
if n = 1
then raise Fail ("hey")
else 2

val t = test 1
```

When I type

```
- use "test.sml";
```

the output is just

```
[opening test.sml]
val it = () : unit
```

I would like it to print that an exception was raised and the message ("hey")

Any ideas on how to fix this
I'm using smlnj 110.82

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't handle your exception.

You should do like:

```
fun test n =
if n = 1
then raise Fail ("hey")
else 2

val t = test 1 handle Fail msg => 0;
```

---

```
[opening practice.sml]
val test = fn : int -> int
val t = 0 : int
val it = () : unit
```

---

if you hope to see Fail msg in your screen, just take use of side effect:

```
fun test n =
if n = 1
then raise Fail ("hey")
else 2

val t = test 1 handle Fail msg => (print (msg ^ "\n"); 0)
```

---

```
[opening practice.sml]
hey
val test = fn : int -> int
val t = 0 : int
val it = () : unit
```